# Unable to evaluate simple expression in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to plot portfolio mean vs standard deviation (scatter plots) for several different values of the correlation between stock returns. However for each different value of the correlation coefficient, I can't seem to be able to get a different value of the standard deviation vector.

```
rA = .05; sA = .00; lA = "A"  # mean and std.dev. and label of stock A returns
rB = .10; sB = .38; lB = "B"  # mean and std.dev. and label of stock B returns

# several possible values of the correlation (There should be one curve for each value)
rrab1 = 1
rrab2 = .5 
rrab3 = 0        # and other such values

# Create portfolio weight vectors (Needed to generate the curves)
x = collect(0 : .05 : 1)   # weight on stock A (a vector)
y = 1 .-x                  # weight on stock B (a vector)

# Evaluate the portfolio mean and the portfolio std.dev.

rab1 = rA*x + rB*y             # Portfolio return
sab1 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab1*sA*sB .*x .* y)    # Portfolio std.dev. for correl = 1

rab2 = rA*x + rB*y
sab2 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab2*sA*sB .*x .* y )    # Portfolio std.dev. for correl = .5

rab3 = rA*x + rB*y
sab3 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab3*sA*sB .*x .* y )      # Portfolio std.dev. for correl = 1

and so on for other possible values of correlation.
```

I want to plot the all the 3 curves in the same r-s axes using PGFPlotsX. But I am getting just a single plot, that for rrab1.

If I check my std.dev. vectors I find that I am unable to get different vectors.

```
sab1 == sab2 == sab3   # outputs true

using DataFrames
s = DataFrame()
s.x = sab1
s.y = sab3
s

outputs:
21 rows × 2 columns
    x   y
    Float64 Float64
1   0.38    0.38
2   0.361   0.361
3   0.342   0.342
4   0.323   0.323
5   0.304   0.304
6   0.285   0.285
7   0.266   0.266
8   0.247   0.247
9   0.228   0.228
10  0.209   0.209
11  0.19    0.19
12  0.171   0.171
13  0.152   0.152
14  0.133   0.133
15  0.114   0.114
16  0.095   0.095
17  0.076   0.076
18  0.057   0.057
19  0.038   0.038
20  0.019   0.019
21  0.0     0.0
```

That is, all the s vectors are the same although the correlations are different.
I am new to Julia and must be missing something elementary.

Comment: Your result is expected as `sA=0.0` so you assume to have one risk-free asset.

Answer (score 2):

I think Bogumil's comment should be an answer - this isn't really a Julia issue but follows directly from your assumptions. You start from:

```
sA = .00
```

and then calculate:

```
sab1 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab1*sA*sB .*x .* y)   
sab2 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab2*sA*sB .*x .* y ) 
sab3 = sqrt.(sA^2*x.^2 + sB^2*y.^2 - 2*rrab3*sA*sB .*x .* y )
```

Simplifying this by using the fact that `sA = 0.0` and therefore all terms multiplied by `sA` vanish:

```
sab1 = sqrt.(sB^2*y.^2)   
sab2 = sqrt.(sB^2*y.^2) 
sab3 = sqrt.(sB^2*y.^2)
```

and indeed

```
julia> sqrt.(sB^2 * y.^2)
21-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.38
 0.361
 0.342
 0.323
 0.304
 0.28500000000000003
 0.26599999999999996
 0.24700000000000003
 0.22799999999999998
 0.20900000000000002
 0.19
 0.17099999999999999
 0.152
 0.13299999999999998
 0.11400000000000002
 0.095
 0.07599999999999998
 0.05700000000000001
 0.03799999999999999
 0.019000000000000017
 0.0
```